# how to replace space with plus(+) url in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-router

I need to remove %20 to + sign angular5 following URL 
http://localhost:4200/listings?item=peter%20in%20england&id=158525

this.router.navigate(['/listings'], { queryParams: { 'item': searchstring, 'id':id}});

http://localhost:4200/listings?item=peter+in+england&id=158525

Comment: `'%20'.replace('%20', '+')` --> `'+'`

Answer (score 2):

> You can use `replace` method here. It will replace all the `space` with `'+'`.

```
this.router.navigate(['/listings'], { queryParams: { 'item': (searchstring||'').replace(/ /g,"+"), 'id':id}});
```

Comment: that also given http://localhost:4200/listings?item=peter%2Bin%2Bengland&id=158525 @surjeet